# Previously Working Flow Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: visual-workflow, external-services

I have a Lightning Component flow that used a very simple external service. It uses basic auth and calls a web service. This was working fine until today when it suddenly stopped working. The web service is no longer called and I now have an error on that step:

```
Error element postMyWebService (FlowActionCall).
Callout failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a double but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 5 path $
```

The issue is not in the processing of the response from the web service as it does not even get that far.

I have confirmed credentials are valid.

I'm stuck as to what to do as I can't seem to get any better debug output and there are no doubles in the parameters for this service call even though it says that it expected a double.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I've hit an identical problem. Our current thinking is that its a problem introduced in the Summer 21 build.

Comment: I think it was introduced in that build. I have control over the webservice that I was using so I added a new webservice call that was a PUT instead of a POST, but otherwise the same. I regenerated the swagger doc and re-added the service in SF and for some reason that worked without error. Very annoying problem though!